# Updating extra fields pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have 3 tables,

a pedido(order) table,  a product table and a pedido_product table
I have an extra field cantidad in the pedido_product table that i´m trying to update for each product orderd

I'm able to update the extra fields with hardcode values in my update method, my cantidad get's updated correctly

```
  $productId = 2; 
  $cantidad = 1.1;
  Pedido::find($pedidoId)->products()->updateExistingPivot($productId, [
 "cantidad" => $cantidad
 ]);
```

Now i have a form where i try to update the cantidad on each product on the same request

```
 {!! Form::open(array('action' => 
 ['PedidosController@update', $pedido->id],'method' => 'PATCH')) !!}
 @foreach ($pedido->products as $product)
 {!! Form::text($product->pivot->product_id, 
  $product->pivot->cantidad, ['class' => 'form-control' ,'id' => 'cantidad']) !!}
```

i get what i want, an array with a key refrenced from the product_id and the value of the to be updated cantidad. but now how do i bind productId and cantidad in the update method to the array i recieve from my form and loop through them in my update method?

```
  $pedido = $request->input();
  $productId =  ? ;
  $cantidad = ? ;
  Pedido::find($pedidoId)->products()->updateExistingPivot($productId, [
  "cantidad" => $cantidad
```

Thanks

edit

---

I didnn't found the ansert but i changed the approach, instead of updating them all at the same time, i update them one by one by opening the form after the loop and passing throug a hidden form that provides the product_id this does the trick

```
 @foreach ($pedido->products as $product)
 {!! Form::open(array('action' => ['PedidosController@update', $pedido->id],'method' => 'PATCH')) !!}
 {!! Form::text('cantidad', $product->pivot->cantidad, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 {!! Form::hidden('id', $product->pivot->product_id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: you can input value by passing the input field name into input method like these `$pedido = $request->input('input_field_name_here');`

Comment: thanks, but i needed a way to bind the productId to the key of the array and the cantidad to the value.
But i solved it by passing through the id via a hidden form. and bind it to the productId